# Content Method in kendo controls

Tags: kendo-ui

I am a beginner to kendo controls. What's the use of `Content` method and `Name` method in kendo controls?

```Razor
<%=Html.Kendo().Button()
   .Name("textButton")
   .HtmlAttributes( new {type = "button"} )
   .Content("Text button") %><br /><br />
```

Comment: As I know, It's all about input classes for using kendo css file. http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/helpers/button/overview  maybe this link can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Name is actually the id attribute which we use in html,and,content is the text of that control.